# How to set the java.lang.ClassCastException (inflater in a View)

Tags: java, android, xml, view

Here is my issue in my xml file :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.thomas.sudoku.vue.grille_boutons.Grille_Boutons cannot be cast to com.example.thomas.sudoku.vue.grille_boutons.Nombre_Bouton   at com.example.thomas.sudoku.vue.grille_boutons.Grille_Boutons$Adapteur_Grille_Boutons.getView

Here is my `getView` method who is called in the message above. Apparently the problem comes from the inflater.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertVue, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertVue;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bouton, parent, false);

        Nombre_Bouton btn;
        btn = (Nombre_Bouton) v;
        btn.setTextSize(10);
        btn.setId(position);

        if (position != 9) {
            btn.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
            btn.setNombre(position + 1);
        } else {
            btn.setText("DEL");
            btn.setNombre(0);
        }
        return btn;
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: can you post xml for R.layout.button

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.thomas.sudoku.vue.grille_boutons.Grille_Boutons
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

The issue might be also the (Nombre_Bouton) v but I have to use it for making this variable a view.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 Nombre_Bouton btn;
        btn = (Nombre_Bouton) v;
```

to

```
Grille_Boutons btn = (Grille_Boutons )v.findViewById(R.id.button);
```